# Why is the TCP/UDP checksum finally complemented?

Tags: tcp, checksum

In TCP/UDP, the sender xors 16-bit words and the final result is complemented again to get the checksum. Now, this is done so that the receiver would recompute the checksum with the data and the checksum and if the result were all ones, it can be certain (well, almost!) that there's no error. My question is why would we have to do a final complement of the result at the sender. We might as well send it as such so that when the receiver recomputes the checksum, it'll have to check for all zeros, instead of all ones like in the other case.

Answer (score 3):

Because 0 has a special meaning. It is used to indicate that checksum computation is to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

So that the receiver can just do a 1's complement sum of the all the data (including the checksum field) and see if it is `-0 (0xffff)`.

Comment: Why can't the receiver take the 1's complement sum and check the data with 0, instead of -0?